# ffmpeg: how to stream from rtmp to FLS?

Tags: ffmpeg, red5

I can create HLS from static MPEG4 using that command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list out.list -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts
```

I am now trying to achieve that:

live RTMP(FME)------->FFMEG-------------->HLS

[image]

I tried with:

`ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/video -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list out.list -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts`

But got error:

> Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
>   rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/video: Unknown error occurred

Any idea how to achieve :

RTMP---->FMPEG----->HLS ?

I also tried :

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/yarek live=1" -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list out.list -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts
```

Seems better but stucks:

```
ble-zlib
```

libavutil      52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
  libavcodec     54. 69.100 / 54. 69.100
  libavformat    54. 35.100 / 54. 35.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 20.106 /  3. 20.106
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 16.100 /  0. 16.100
  libpostproc    52.  1.100 / 52.  1.100
**rtmp server sent error**
Metadata:
  videokeyframe_frequency8.00
  avclevel              31.00
  videodevice           Microsoft LifeCam Cinema
  keywords
  width                 320.00
  videodatarate         350.00
  presetname            Custom
  copyright
  creationdate          Mon Oct 29 17:51:08 2012
  videocodecid          avc1
  author
  avcprofile            66.00
  title
  height                240.00
  description
  rating
  framerate             20.00

Thanks

Comment: Can you read the input stream with ffmpeg? Maybe the problem has nothing to do with the output settings.

Comment: yes I can read it with ffplay.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/video -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/livepkgr/video
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.